# Parsing Unicode in a byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, unicode

I have a byte array with a series of characters. In one case I have

```
[28] = 0x6e
[29] = 0x61
[30] = 0x6d
[31] = 0x65
[32] = 0x00
[33] = 0x00
[34] = 0x00
[35] = 0x4f
[36] = 0x08
[37] = 0x00
[38] = 0x07
[39] = 0x00
[40] = 0x00
[41] = 0x04
[42] = 0x13
[43] = 0xff
[44] = 0xff
[45] = 0x00
[46] = 0x00
```

28 to 31 has the characters "name" with that section ending on element 32. Then I have another byte array:

```
[47] = 0x01
[48] = 0x03
[49] = 0x00
[50] = 0x00
[51] = 0x73
[52] = 0x65
[53] = 0xc3
[54] = 0xb1
[55] = 0x6f
[56] = 0x72
[57] = 0x00
[58] = 0x00
[59] = 0x00
[60] = 0x4f
[61] = 0x08
[62] = 0x00
[63] = 0x08
[64] = 0x00
[65] = 0x00
[66] = 0x04
[67] = 0x13
[68] = 0xff
[69] = 0xff
[70] = 0x00
[71] = 0x00
```

where I believe I have the string `señor`.

With the first array it's easy to find the name as the first 4 bytes with `00` as a terminator but how do I decipher whats on the second byte array?

Both arrays are `vector<char>`s.

Comment: It seems like it is using [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding.

Comment: What Unicode? UTF16, UTF8? BTW C++11 and later have utf16 literals so you don't need to parse anything. If bytes 28-31 are `name`, you probably use UTF8. In any case, a UTF8 string in C++ *is* a std::string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - how do I know where the name ends in the 2nd byte array?

Comment: Check [C++ String and Character Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx) for the current state of Unicode support. What do you want to do with this array? Do you want to display it? Work with individual characters? It may be easier to convert it to a char16_t/u16string

Comment: If you don't know in advance the used UTF[8/16/32] or Windows Codepage encode, the only option is try-error method. You should learn at least the differences between UTF8 and UTF16 and Codepage.

Comment: @Ripi2 it's pretty obvious this is UTF8 because of `name`. And Unicode is a sore subject in C++

Comment: @ruipacheco Check the [codecvt](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) library and the examples. You may be able to use it to manipulate UTF8 strings. I say "may" because some compilers may have issues

Comment: This array has a utf8 string and other values I need. I want to parse it and possibly display the string.

Comment: @ruipacheco check codecvt then. The example does exactly that

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You did try-error without a computer ;)
The UTF8 encoding uses a variable number of bytes, depending on the character (the Unicode code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is obviously using `UTF-8` encoding:

```
[53] = 0xc3
[54] = 0xb1
```

This is the [UTF-8 encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) <kbd>ñ</kbd> character. And the surrounding characters are the remaining four characters in `señor`.

The C++ library does have some facilities for [working with UTF-8](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8); but I always found those library classes somewhat awkward and inflexible. On most platforms, you have an excellent, flexible [iconv library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) with a simple, easy API for converting between UTF-8 and other encodings.

Comment: How do I know where the unicode string ends in the byte array?

Comment: By understanding where the strings come from, and what process creates them. There is no sign that individual bytes wear around their neck that say "this is where the string ends". In C-style strings, they get terminated by a `'\0'` byte. If these are C-style strings, that's how you find their end.